# yarn finds react but not npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am using `yarn install` to install packages from my `package.json` file, in particular, react. When I check if react is there with yarn, everthing checks out:

```
HAL-9000 wogsland$ yarn list react
yarn list v0.24.6
└─ react@15.4.2
✨  Done in 1.26s.
```

However, npm cannot find react:

```
HAL-9000 wogsland$ npm ls react
my-project@1.0.1 /Users/wogsland/Projects/my-project
└── UNMET DEPENDENCY react@https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-
15.4.2.tgz 

npm ERR! missing: react@https://registry.npmjs.org/react/-/react-15.4.2.tgz, required by my-project@1.0.1
```

I am trying to run my unit tests with npm, so this is a problem. However, running an `npm install` is not an option because it farks what the yarn install has done.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to fix this dependency issue?

Comment: npm doesn't understand yarn's folder structures. So what're asking is impossible. Only use 1 package manager

Comment: Dang. I'm getting the same errors in my tests when I run `yarn test`. Might be barking up the wrong tree here. Didn't think I could do that though. Thanks, @thangngoc89!

Comment: Try deleting your lock files? You should be listing 15.6.1 (the latest).

Comment: @Win Thanks, tried that, but `yarn.lock` wasn't it. And I don't want to upgrade to 15.6.1 yet because it generates so many warnings about my syntax being outdated.